# Saving the duplicate rows in a seperate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am able to delete the duplicate rows using pandas,

`df.drop_duplicates(subset=['issuer_id', 'hios_plan_identifier', 'group_or_individual_plan_type'])` . 
For I know , it drops all the duplicates keeping the first occurrence which is the default functionality.

My requirement is that I want to save the dropped data to a another dataframe checking on a subsets of columns.

I have my dataframe `df`,

```
  issuer_id hios_plan_identifier  plan_year group_or_individual_plan_type
0        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
1        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
2        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
3        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
```

I want to drop the duplicates from `df`(will have only 1 row) and save the rest in another dataframe `df1` (will have 3 rows).

Comment: All values in column `hios_plan_identifier ` are unique, so no duplicates in the example. Please check it.

Comment: My bad.. updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and assign the values to `df1` and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on df:

```
subset_col = ['issuer_id', 'hios_plan_identifier', 'group_or_individual_plan_type']
df1 = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=subset_col),:]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=subset_col)

print(df)
   issuer_id hios_plan_identifier  plan_year group_or_individual_plan_type
0        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group

print(df1)
   issuer_id hios_plan_identifier  plan_year group_or_individual_plan_type
1        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
2        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
3        484      99806CAAUSJ-TMP       2018                         Group
```